# Local full text index for a directory tree, a quicker alternative for grep -R

Tags: linux, ubuntu, search, grep, full-text-search

I have a large directory tree of source files. I want to search around all these files. My first instinct is to use `grep -R` or `ack`, but either way they just sequentially read all the files.

Is there some lightweight programme that I can install that will scan all the files once, build and index, and then at any later date I can search for certain words? That should be quicker than just doing loads of `grep`'s. The files I want to search won't be changing, so I don't need something that will index files automatically.

I'm not looking for something that will scan all the files on my harddrive, and i want something locally that's easy to install and set up on a local desktop machine, for simple almost throwaway searching.

Bonus points if the software in the normal ubuntu repositories.

Ideally I want something that's as easy to use as this:

```
sudo aptitude install supersearch
cd /path/to/where/I/wanna/search
supersearch --make-index 
supersearch "foo bar"
```

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you want [Beagle](http://beagle-project.org/).  Its main purpose is as a comprehensive desktop search, but you can tell it to just look at the source tree you want to index.

Answer (score 4):

I believe [Tracker](http://projects.gnome.org/tracker/) is installed by default on Ubuntu. Do `man trackerd` and `man tracker-search` for more info.

From the `trackerd` man page:

> By  default,  trackerd  will index all files in a user’s home directory
>          (with the exception of hidden files). This can be overridden by  speci‐
>          fying  one  or more directories to be indexed instead in the configura‐
>          tion  file  ($HOME/.config/tracker/tracker.cfg)  and/or  by  using  the
>          --include-dir option to specify other directories to be indexed.

Comment: I played with tracker briefly and it looks like it does what I want which is similar to the OP.